# how can you tell if the SQL express is being bottleneck-ed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

What is the simplest way to find out whether MS SQL databases (10.x & 11.x) are hitting the express edition limit?

Comment: The only limits I'm aware of in SQL Express are database size (10 GB), max RAM usage (1 GB), and max cores (4).  What bottleneck are you referring to?

Comment: just the ones you mentioned. Mostly though, whether the RAM usage is running at full capacity. Is it possible to tell from the SQL Management Studio?